# Azure Table Service REST API error

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I would like to execute inset table entity REST API in Table Storage Service but it doesn't work.

I referred [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/insert-entity) doc.

My request code is here,

```
<?php
// storage account name
$account = "mystgaccount";
$tablestoragename = "mytablename";
$accessKey = "myaccesskey";
$date = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s T',time());
$api_version = "2015-12-11";
$url = "https://$account.table.core.windows.net/$tablestoragename";
$method = "POST";
$body = '{"Address":"MountainView","Age":23,"AmountDue":200.23,"CustomerCode@odata.type":"Edm.Guid","CustomerCode":"c9da6455-213d-42c9-9a793e9149a57833","CustomerSince@odata.type":"Edm.DateTime","CustomerSince":"2008-0710T00:00:00","IsActive":true,"NumberOfOrders@odata.type":"Edm.Int64","NumberOfOrders":"255","PartitionKey":"mypartitionkey","RowKey":"myrowkey"}';

$stringToSign = [
// VERB
$method,
// Content-MD5
'',
// Content-Type
'',
// Date
$date,
];

$stringToSign = array_merge($stringToSign, ["/$account/$tablestoragename"]);
$stringToSign = implode("\n", $stringToSign);
$signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $stringToSign, base64_decode($accessKey), true));

$headers = [
"x-ms-date:{$date}",
"x-ms-version:$api_version",
"Authorization:SharedKey $account:{$signature}",
"Content-Type: application/json",
];

$ch = curl_init();

$options = array(
CURLOPT_URL => $url,
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => $method,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE,
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($body),
);

curl_setopt_array($ch, $proxy_options);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

$response  = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($response);
echo curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Response

```
"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"><m:code>AuthenticationFailed</m:code><m:message xml:lang="en-US">Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:b93fe560-0002-0028-129a-571361000000
Time:2017-11-07T07:34:13.3303714Z</m:message></m:error>"
```

I read related questions but it hasn't resolved yet :(

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: AuthenticationFailed: wrong account data?

Comment: Thank you for replying, Kim. I confirmed my account but it is not wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible reason for this error could be because of `Content-Type` header. You're specifying this header in your request but is not included in your `$stringToSign`. Please try again by changing your `$stringToSign` to something like:

```
$stringToSign = [
// VERB
$method,
// Content-MD5
'',
// Content-Type
'application/json',
// Date
$date,
];
```

Comment: Hi Gaurav, thank you for your replying. I added Content-Type to signature but there is another error. "One of the request inputs is not valid." Does it mean that the body has problem?

Comment: I found a mistake. The body json had already encoded so it doesn't need http_build_query. Thank you everyone, it works!